# Convert Mat to Vec<u8> (Rust OpenCV)

Tags: opencv, types, rust, casting

I'm really new to Rust and fairly new to OpenCV (yea).

I have a simple OpenCV example working in a seperate POC. But then integrating it into a workflow pipeline I need to return a buffer in type `Vec<u8>`.

Img is a [Mat](https://docs.rs/opencv/0.19.3/opencv/core/struct.Mat.html) object which has this `to_vec_2d` method. But I'm unsure how to cast it to u8?

I'm thinking I might have to iterate through the Mat type. Is it possible to map it u8?

```rust
fn edge_detect(width: u32, height: u32, bytes: Vec<u8>, _metadata: Metadata) -> (u32, u32, Vec<u8>) {
    let img = imdecode(&Vector::from_iter(bytes), imgcodecs::IMREAD_ANYCOLOR).expect("Failed to decode");
    let mut result = img.clone();
    canny(&img, &mut result, 100.0, 200.0, 3, false).expect("Failed to find edges");
    let vec_result : Vec<u8> = result.to_vec_2d().expect("Cannot convert to vector");
    (width, height, vec_result)
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`flat_map`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.flat_map) on an iterator to get them:

```rust
fn main() {
    let vec_2d = vec![vec![0, 1], vec![2, 3]];
    let v: Vec<u8> = vec_2d.iter().flat_map(|v| v.iter()).cloned().collect();
    println!("{:?}", v);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=4e68e2277c239f775c8262e965232411)